# Filtering rows in a text file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have tab delimited text file (like this):

```
A  1 A1g DELL
A  1 B1s HP
A  7 Zfd Nog
A  5 Jgf KIT
A  1 Def JOP
```

Apart from the first row, I would like to keep only the rows where the second column's value is larger than 1.

```
A  1 A1g DELL
A  7 Zfd Nog
A  5 Jgf KIT
```

I tried `awk '{if($2>1) print }' file.txt` but it omits the first row. How can I skip the first row and check the condition `($2 >1)` for other rows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AWK:

```
$ awk 'NR==1||$2>1' test.in
A  1 A1g DELL
A  7 Zfd Nog
A  5 Jgf KIT
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to spare the last row, then `awk 'NR==5 || $2 >1'` works, how to tell awk to spare only the last row by not providing 5 directly,

Comment: Probably store current record into a variable and process it in the next round before storing the now-current record into the same variable (wow that's hard to word out, easier to code): `awk 'NR>1&&b>1{print a}{a=$0;b=$2}END{print a}' test.in` prints lines 3,4 and 5.

Comment: Recent versions of **GNU awk** provides the special patterns [BEGINFILE and ENDFILE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html#index-ENDFILE-pattern).